# how combine more then two songs in core java code?

Tags: java

I want to combine the song's in the format of mp4, mp3, Avi and wmv etc into one single file with help of Java code as in my server I have only JDK environment , so far I am using core Java file operation code. as follows.

```
    String str="E:\\Movies\\Dark Skies (2013)\\Dark.mp4";

    String ftr="F:\\CRS\\stv.mp4";

    File file=new File(str);
    File Kile=new File(ftr);

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);

    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(Kile);

    int luffersize=102400000;
    byte[] luffer=new byte[luffersize];

    int lenght=(int) fis.available();


    if ((fis.read(luffer)) != 0) {
            try {
                fos.write(luffer, 0, lenght);
                System.out.println("working");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                fis.close();
                fos.close();

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Different file types contain different information. You can't simply throw all of the bytes into a single file and hope that it works. You'll need to find a library that was written to modify MP3/MP4/AVI/etc files appropriately and use that.

Comment: What do you mean by "combining"? 1. Mixing them? 2. Putting one after the other? 3. Or just put them in a container (like in a ZIP)? If you chose 1 or 2 you will need to study thoroughly the specification of MP3 format first.

Comment: Combining files means "Writing the byte stream of two files in the single files  and while playing the audio or video it should play one after another"

Comment: hi justin niessener , please run the code given by me and check it out!! am able concatenate two files of same format into a single valid file !! which is working fine while playing.. Kindly don't reply without knowledge of java file operation !! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code I whipped up to demonstrate how to concatenate (sequentially combine) two files together.

This doesn't take into account the MP4 file format. I'm not familiar with MP4, but MP3 is simply a series of 512-byte chunks with an arbitrary ID3 header. If you can strip off the header on the second file, general concatenation (i.e. "cat song1.mp song2.mp3 > newsong.mp3") of two music files does work reliably. But I'm not familiar with MP4 and I'm pretty sure it can support a variety of codecs. Hence, YMMV with this solution.  Otherwise, do formal parsing and streaming with a codec library.

In any case, here's some sample code that will combine two files together:

```
public void CombineFiles(String filename1, String filename2, String filenameOuput) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(filename1);
    FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(filename2);
    FileOutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(filenameOuput);
    FileInputStream stream = stream1;

    byte [] buffer = new byte[8192]; // 8K temp buffer should suffice

    while (true)
    {
        int bytesread = stream.read(buffer);
        if (bytesread != -1)
        {
            streamOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle end of file and moving to the next file
            if (stream == stream2)
                break;
            else
                stream = stream2;
        }
    }

    streamOut.close();
    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for above code  SELBIE !!!

above code given by me is working perfectly fine to combine mp3 files (generally audio songs),
but while combine in mp4 format(video files) it's writing first fileinputstream correctly but  not able to write second files stream in the same file. ANY help for mp4 or avi (video format)
files . Thanks in advance

Comment: ANy help for concatenating video file(mp4 format) through java code !!!! thanks in advance

Comment: @IrfanPervez - If you like the checkbox, give it an upvote. MP3 is both a codec and a container format all in one. It plays nice with rudimentary splits and concatenation.  But MP4 is just a container format. Two different MP4 files can be entirely different encodings and stream types. Hence, what does it mean to concatenate an H264 video file recorded at 720p with another file that is AAC audio only? You need to find an MP4 parsing/writing library that will let you read and write the raw codec streams. Another person posted, then retracted this link: https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/